# Installing proxychains. HELP NEEDED!

Tags: installation, command-line, kernel, compiling, gcc

OK so i am new to linux. I am trying to install proxychains but im sure it has dependencies that i do not have on my system can somebody look at the following script and tell me the list of packages i need to install using apt-get.

```
pr0jectzer0@pr0jectzer0-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  help  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
pr0jectzer0@pr0jectzer0-OptiPlex-GX620:~$ cd Desktop
pr0jectzer0@pr0jectzer0-OptiPlex-GX620:~/Desktop$ ls
Programming      proxychains-3.1.tar.gz  TorBrowser_en-US.app
proxychains-3.1  tor                     tor-browser-gnu-linux-i686-2.3.25-6-dev-en-US.tar.gz
pr0jectzer0@pr0jectzer0-OptiPlex-GX620:~/Desktop$ cd proxychains-3.1
pr0jectzer0@pr0jectzer0-OptiPlex-GX620:~/Desktop/proxychains-3.1$ ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for working aclocal-1.4... missing
checking for working autoconf... missing
checking for working automake-1.4... missing
checking for working autoheader... missing
checking for working makeinfo... missing
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for g77... no
checking for f77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for f90... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for correct ltmain.sh version... yes
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating proxychains/Makefile
config.status: creating proxychains/docs/Makefile
config.status: creating proxychains/docs/en/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing default-1 commands
pr0jectzer0@pr0jectzer0-OptiPlex-GX620:~/Desktop/proxychains-3.1$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pr0jectzer0/Desktop/proxychains-3.1'
Making all in proxychains
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/pr0jectzer0/Desktop/proxychains-3.1/proxychains'
Making all in docs
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/pr0jectzer0/Desktop/proxychains-3.1/proxychains/docs'
Making all in en
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/pr0jectzer0/Desktop/proxychains-3.1/proxychains/docs/en'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/pr0jectzer0/Desktop/proxychains-3.1/proxychains/docs/en'
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/pr0jectzer0/Desktop/proxychains-3.1/proxychains/docs'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/pr0jectzer0/Desktop/proxychains-3.1/proxychains/docs'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/pr0jectzer0/Desktop/proxychains-3.1/proxychains/docs'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/pr0jectzer0/Desktop/proxychains-3.1/proxychains'
/bin/bash ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I..     -g -O2 -c libproxychains.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -g -O2 -Wp,-MD,.deps/libproxychains.pp -c libproxychains.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libproxychains.o
libproxychains.c:291:5: error: conflicting types for 'getnameinfo'
/usr/include/netdb.h:679:12: note: previous declaration of 'getnameinfo' was here
make[3]: *** [libproxychains.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/pr0jectzer0/Desktop/proxychains-3.1/proxychains'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pr0jectzer0/Desktop/proxychains-3.1/proxychains'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pr0jectzer0/Desktop/proxychains-3.1'
make: *** [all-recursive-am] Error 2
pr0jectzer0@pr0jectzer0-OptiPlex-GX620:~/Desktop/proxychains-3.1$
```

As you can see i have not made it to $ sudo make install

Please help im getting stressed lol.

Answer (score 8):

To install proxychains, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install proxychains
```

I just used that command, and it worked.  See image below

[image]